# Некорректно показывается сайт

Tags: html

Есть сайт http://test2.univer.biz
Всё было всегда хорошо. Сейчас захожу в на него, у меня там он не растягивается на фулл-ширину, хотя ничего не меняли. Если зайти с другого браузера, устройства, всё нормально, всё ок.

Что я пробовал:
ctrl + f5
f12 - очистка кэша и жёсткая перезагрузка
CCLEANER - очистка
Настройки в браузере - очистка кэша
Перезагрузка ПК.

Как это починить, я не могу понять.

Я не уверен, что такое разрешено на этом сайте. Если кто сможет мне помочь, я готов финансово отблагодарить. Надеюсь, можно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы попробуйте переустановить браузер

Comment: Попробовать можно, но это не даёт 100% гарантии. А вспоминать все пароли не хочется.

Comment: А у вас какой браузер?

Comment: Хром. Я тут разных пользователей создал, под одним всё нормально, под вторым нет.

Comment: 1. Перейдите chrome://settings/content/zoomLevels и посмотрите нормальный ли на сайте масштаб

Comment: 2. А если ничего не получится вы всегда можете посмотреть свои пароли тут chrome://settings/passwords

Comment: Боже... Я просто походу случайно нажал ctrl + minus... Давай свяжемся в ЛС, для вознаграждение, тут есть такое-же? @youmixx отпиши в телегу.